# Visual Studio Code formats on save no matter what I do. How do I stop this?

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I am using python (django syntax) inside an html file:

```html
<form action="{% url 'home:favorite' album.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
      <input type="radio" id="song{{ forloop.counter }}" name="song" value="{{ song.id }}" />
      <label for="song{{ forloop.counter }}">
          {{ song.song_title }}
          {% if song.is_favorite %}
              **
          {% endif %}
      </label><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Favorite">
</form>
```

No matter what I do in the VS Code settings.json (for user OR workspace) it formats the code like this:

```html
<form action="{% url 'home:favorite' album.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" id="song{{ forloop.counter }}" name="song" value="{{ song.id }}" />
    <label for="song{{ forloop.counter }}">
        {{ song.song_title }}
        {% if song.is_favorite %}
            **
        {% endif %}
    </label>
    <br> {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Favorite">
</form>
```

(pushes the `{% for song in album.song_set.all %}` among other things to the previous line and keeps it from being on its own line.

Here are my vs code settings:

```html
{
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "editor.formatOnType": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.glyphMargin": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.wordWrap": true
}
```

These settings are the same for both user and workspace. Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the [JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter) extension for VS Code was formatting it that way and I had to disable it.

Zach