# vscode html autoformat on django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates, visual-studio-code

I love VSCode on save autoformat until it messed up with my template code.

It wrongly formats my django template syntax into one line code (sometimes really long line). So instead of having this code

```
{% for row in 'ABCDEFGH' %}
<tr>
  {% for col in '123456789012345' %}
    <td>
      {% with forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" as counter %}
        {% with row|add:counter as seat_num %}
          {% if seat_num not in oc_seats %}
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ row }}{{ forloop.counter }}" name="seats">
          {% endif %}
          <br> {{ seat_num }} 
        {% endwith %}
      {% endwith %}
     </td>    
   {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I end up have this code

```
{% for row in 'ABCDEFGH' %}
<tr>
  {% for col in '123456789012345' %}
  <td style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #aaa;">
    {% with forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" as counter %} {% with row|add:counter as seat_num %} {% if seat_num not in oc_seats %}
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ row }}{{ forloop.counter }}" name="seats"> {% endif %} {{ seat_num }} {% endwith %} {% endwith %}
  </td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to disable format on save by changing user settings into `{"editor.formatOnSave": false}` but still haven't gotten any luck.

Is there any configuration that I can use to make it work better?

PS: 
I'm using VSCode version 1.9 on Sierra MacOSx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is no document formatter for 'django-html'-files installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175822/there-is-no-document-formatter-for-django-html-files-installed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can disable the default html formatter, goto File > Preferences > User or Workspace Settings, in HTML settings you will find :

```
// Enable/disable default HTML formatter (requires restart)
  "html.format.enable": true,
```

I think VSCode uses js-beautify as default formatter, you can use [beautify extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) to override it settings with .jsbeautifyrc in project directory

Answer (score 29):

I used the beautify extension instead which worked right away while prettier was still putting on one line. Credit goes to [kimanihuon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12130316/kimanihuon) on this stackoverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175822/there-is-no-document-formatter-for-django-html-files-installed/63091040#63091040).

1. Add the following to settings.json

> ```
> "files.associations": {
>    "**/*.html": "html",
>    "**/templates/*/*.html": "django-html",
>    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
>    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
> },
>
> "emmet.includeLanguages": {
>    "django-html": "html"
> },
> ```

2. Install beautify and then add following to settings.json

> ```
> "beautify.language": {
>    "html": [
>        "htm",
>        "html",
>        "django-html"
>    ]
> },
> ```

3. Restart VSCode just in case

Comment: beautify completes the trick!

Comment: Beautify no longer exists

Comment: Try djlint, see one of the answers below

Answer (score 23):

Alexa has a good point in [her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331301/4683950). The file mode needs to be changed in  "Django/HTML" to prevent VS CODE for formatting it.

How to change the file mode?

A quick solution is to use [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django) called vscode-Django and adjust your setting like this as said in his documentation.

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt"
}
```

With those setting any file located in the template folder will be considered as a Django template file and will not be affected by HTML autoformat.

PS: The extension is still in preview mode, hope it will get better with time.

Answer (score 18):

Changing the language mode of the file to "Django/HTML" will also prevent VSCode from autoformatting it.

Comment: How to change the language mode of a file?

Comment: In the footer at the bottom right of VSCode application you can click on the current detected language and change it

Comment: Do I need to install a specific extension to see this language mode? I do not have it.

Comment: The button itself does not say 'language mode', but rather the currently detected language, like 'HTML'

Comment: No extension needed!

Comment: You've got to install the Django extension

Answer (score 7):

Prettier in VSCode was the culprit in my situation. I got it to stop formatting with following in my `settings.json`.

```json
"files.associations": {
   "**/*.html": "html",
   "**/templates/*/*.html": "django-html",
   "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
   "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},    
"[django-html]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "batisteo.vscode-django"
},
```

`files.associations` sets the language mode for the templates to django-html.
`[django-html]` sets the settings for that language mode. As of writing this, the formatter in `batisteo.vscode-django` doesn't do anything for me (so it's the same as `null` in its place), but I left it there in case the django extension ever does.

Answer (score 6):

I tried and now highly recommend the [djLint](https://djlint.com/) extension to format Django-HTML code. It is effective and quite configurable.

You need to install the [Python extension](https://djlint.com/) (works with venv) and the [VSCode extension](https://github.com/monosans/djlint-vscode).

With your code, the output is:

```html
{% for row in 'ABCDEFGH' %}
    <tr>
        {% for col in '123456789012345' %}
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #aaa;">
                {% with forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" as counter %}
                    {% with row|add:counter as seat_num %}
                        {% if seat_num not in oc_seats %}
                            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ row }}{{ forloop.counter }}" name="seats">
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ seat_num }}
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endwith %}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Since beautify is dead this is the best option I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, found a post where the person disabled JS-CSS-HTML Formatter extension (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42100808/4812548) and it fixed the issue. Tested on mine and it seems to have worked too. Hope that helps

Comment: Funny thing is I don't even have that extension, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the formatting option for some of the languages:

Go to Extensions and then "Extension settings" of Prettier and add *django-html* for this case as below.

[image: disable language - prettier]

Answer (score 1):

vscode eslint does not work on Django files. so to disable the prettier extension just add this to your settings.json

```
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  },
```

A similar solution would be

```
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
```

worked for me.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

in VSCode's settings.json, add the following : `emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}`

Comment: what will this do?

Comment: Could you explain why this is a solution, instead of just saying what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found [Better Jinja](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml) extension very useful this allows correct formatting of <kbd>django-template</kbd> and emmet abbreviations for <kbd>HTML</kbd>.

- Open settings by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and search "Open User Settings (JSON)"
- Add following code in JSON file

```json
"material-icon-theme.languages.associations": {
  "jinja-html": "html"
},
"files.associations": {
  "*.html": "jinja-html"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "jinja-html": "html"
},
```

- Make sure you've installed **Better Jinja** extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had Prettier installed, but it wasn't working for me and I couldn't find settings that would make it do what I wanted.

Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72215758/17767334), I installed [djlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=monosans.djlint), then VSCode told me to run `/usr/local/bin/python3.9 -m pip install -U djlint`, so I did, and now it seems to be working alright.