# There is no document formatter for 'django-html'-files installed

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

In vscode, shift+alt+f for auto-formatting does work in HTML, but not work for Django template file.
How can I use autoformatting function in VS code?

Answer (score 12):

The following worked for me:

1. Ensure you have the following in your settings.json (Edit accordingly) :

```
    "files.associations": {
        "**/*.html": "html",
        "**/templates/*/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/*": "django-html",
        "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "django-html": "html"
    },
```

2. Install the beautify extension, then add:

```
    "beautify.language": {
        "html": [
            "htm",
            "html",
            "django-html"
        ]
    },
```

3. May require restart (or may not)

Comment: This is great @kimanihuon. I used prettier for other projects and file types but it would destroy a lot of template tags like breaking {% for %} over several lines which is invalid. I did need to apply the additional setting Romain Straet mentions further down to make it work on macOS 10.15.7.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using prettier and needs the beautify only for `django-html`,

```json
{
    "prettier.disableLanguages": ["django-html"],
    "beautify.language": {
      "html": [
        "django-html"
      ]
    },
    "[django-html]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Beautify then

- Reach to the extension in the extensions list
- Click the Cogwheel and then Click "Extension Settings"
- Scroll down to "Beautify: Language" then Click "Edit in settings.json"
- Scroll down to HTML list and add " ,"django-html" " to the list

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple great Django helpers available in the VSCode plugins directory, but I don't believe there is a Django template formatter plugin available at this time. I'd like one too!

The most useful one I've found is [this](https://github.com/compulim/vscode-indent-4to2) auto-indenter.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I spent too much timte on this. By the way, do you know how to use html auto formatter for 'Django-html' file  ?

Comment: The plugin "prettier" does a good job with HTML, but django template tags confuse it (well, anything it doesn't recognize as valid html confuses it). https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode

Answer (score 1):

Further to hkimani's answer, one additional step was required on my side to make Beautify the default formatter (and be able to format on save) :

```
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Beautify works better than prettier with django html

Answer (score 0):

go to file->preferences->settings  tab workspace  search beautify config edit `beautify:config`  
result my config

```
{
   "[django-html]": {

        "files.associations": {
           "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
          "**/templates/*": "django-txt"
     },
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
    }
},
"beautify.language": {

    "js": {
        "type": [
            "javascript",
            "json",
            "jsonc"
        ],
        "filename": [
            ".jshintrc",
            ".jsbeautifyrc"
        ]
    },
    "css": [
        "css",
        "less",
        "scss"
    ],
    "html": [
        "htm",
        "html",
        "django-html"
    ]
},
"beautify.config": ""
 }
```