# Django doesn't load static file and throws error although syntax is correct - is VS Code the culprit?

Tags: python, django, frontend, backend

I have been working with Django for a few days and I'm trying to get the hang of static files and how to integrate them in my project.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="background_image"
      style="background-image: url({% static 'images/home_slider.jpg' %});">
</div>
```

And Python throws this error for this specific block of code:
[image]

I have more than 30 cases in the same file where I used this pattern `{% static 'something' %}` and it works in all cases. The only difference between these cases in the one above (that's not working) is that the one above is the only one where I apply the style directly on the HTML tag.

I am am my wits' end. From what I researched, the syntax seems to be correct for adding a background image directly in HTML so I'm starting to believe that the error is caused by the fact that VS code is formatting my code in a super weird way when saving and I get something like:

```
<div
                class="background_image"
                style="
                  background-image: url({%static'images/home_slider.jpg'%});
                "
              ></div>
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep space between `static` and `value` inside. So, do:

```
<div class="background_image" style="background-image:url({% static 'images/home_slider.jpg' %});">
</div>
```

Also, if you are having problem with vscode formatting in `django-template`, I would suggest you to install an extension. *Baptiste Darthenay* with name *django[Extension Identifier: batisteo.vscode-django]* which will automatically not format the wrong way. After, installation make sure that you your language mode for that file is `Django/HTML` at the right bottom corner side next to `LF/CRLF`.

Or,

You can disable formatting. Follow this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42579476/10860596).

Comment: Thx. It only worked after I disabled formatting all together. I think your code has too many quotes tho', the url shouldn't be wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Okay.. I have updated as of your suggestion. Thanks!!